# What exactly does value initialization of a pointer do in C++?

Tags: c++

I have seen the related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3197557/391161) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1613383/391161) on this, but I wanted confirmation, because none of them make this explicit.

Suppose I have a class `Foo` and a member `bar` of type `int*`.

**Are the following two initializations entirely equivalent?**

```
Foo::Foo() : bar(NULL) // null pointer constant by macro
{
}

Foo::Foo() : bar() // value initialization
{
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Value-initialization* of a pointer initializes it to a null pointer value; therefore both initializer lists are equivalent.

---

Pointers don't have class or array type, so value initialization for them is *zero initialization*. (8.5p8)

Then, (8.5p6)

> To *zero-initialize* an object or reference of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a scalar type (3.9), the object is initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal `0` (zero) to `T`

This integer literal `0` is a *null pointer constant* (4.10p1), which when converted to a pointer type creates a *null pointer value*.

---

Note that zero-initialization of variables with static and thread duration (3.6.2) also initializes pointers to null pointer values.

---

Above paragraph references are from C++1y draft n3936, but they were the same in earlier drafts I checked also.

Comment: Does that it is not equivalent in older C++ versions?

Comment: @merlin2011: The behavior hasn't changed, but the paragraph numbers have.  In C++03 the corresponding rules are combined in 8.5p5.